# What is wrong with this SQL INSERT?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sql-insert

I'm trying to pass 3 values into existing rows inside a SQLite database based on specific ID that is already inside said row.

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO anime (title, img, synopsis) VALUES (?, ?, ?) WHERE malid = ?", [title, img, synopsis, x])
```

I've tried all sorts of combinations but keep getting errors, in this case just

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a legal insert statement. `insert` means add a new row. What is the `where` clause supposed to be applying to?

Comment: If you want to alter an existing row, you need an `update` statement, not an `insert`.

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE` statement can not be used within `INSERT` command. It is only used in commands which there is an state of selection; like `UPDATE` or `SELECT`.
Logically thinking, that makes no sense inserting and filtering the same time! Everything that comes into `VALUES` when using `INSERT` command will be added to the end of table.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `WHERE` clause in a `INSERT ... VALUES ...` statement.

I suspect that you want to update a row in your table and not insert a new row:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE anime SET (title, img, synopsis) = (?, ?, ?) WHERE malid = ?", (title, img, synopsis, x))
```